# The extent of NP-Completeness

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete

I am told that if a decision problem that is in **NP** Complete can be solved in polynomial time, then **P**=**NP**. However, would this mean that we would instantly have an algorithm to solve *any* **NP** problem. Like if someone solved the traveling salesman problem, would that mean that we would instantly have an algorithm to factor large integers? Or instead, would it mean that an algorithm exists to factor large integers, but it would still be very difficult to find that algorithm, and we would just have the assurance from a theoretical perspective that such an algorithm exists.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: This question might have been answered on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no, even if we assume P $\not=$ NP was not proven. It depends on how someone "solved" the traveling salesman problem.

---

If someone constructed a polynomial-time algorithm that solves the traveling salesman problem, we would be able to instantly specify a polynomial-time algorithm that factors integers. This is the "yes" part of the answer.

If someone proved non-constructively that there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that solves the traveling salesman problem, we would instantly know there exists a polynomial-time algorithm that factors integers. This is the "no" part of the answer, since "it would still be very difficult to find an algorithm" that factors integers in polynomial time, as you have noted.

There are other possible situations. For example, it is possible that "the P versus NP problem may be independent of standard axiom systems like ZFC", quoted from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem#Results_about_difficulty_of_proof). In that case, it may need significant effort to understand the exact meaning of "someone solved the polynomial-time traveling saleman problem."